# Google Forms - This form contains features which require sign in

Tags: google-forms

**Dears,**

I created a Google Form with ability to upload file option. 
It works fine for me when I'm logged-in.

I have shared the link with my friends after making it public to all.

It keeps giving me the following message:

[image: Look at this!]

I make sure that "Requires sign in:" --> "Limit to 1 response" is NOT enabled.

Also, this Quiz is NOT enabled.

What's wrong?

Note that I'm using new version of Google Forms.

Comment: No body can answer this question please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your cooperation, as per Google Forms official forum reply, login is a requirement to upload images from Google Forms:

> Just wanted to let you know, when you ask the respondents to upload files in Google Forms, it will ask them to sign in as the image will be inserted via Google Drive. Unless we are not signed into Drive, we won't be able add or insert images in the form. This is working as intended. Besides this, if the respondents are trying to fill in the form, then they don't require any sign in for that.

Link: [Google Forms Official Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/docs/F1feWdjwCZA/GlIRkQDPBAAJ)

Regards,
Ali

Comment: Even if your upload field is not even for uploading files (e.g.: a drawing signature).  Google is pretty retarded indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that at least one of the following settings could be enabled. If so, please disable them then get back to me and say whether it worked.

- Limit to one response (settings)
- Collect email addresses (settings)
- Send response receipts (settings)
- Collect usernames (under the 'send' menu)

If turning all of these all doesn't work, please upload a screenshot of your settings page for this form.